# Rust reference dropped here while still borrowed

Tags: rust, lifetime

The issue: I'm getting a "XXXXXXX dropped here while still borrowed" error from a method where XXXXXXX is valid to the end of the method (which is fine), but Rust is unnecessarily expecting it to live as long as the input references because those have an explicit lifetime.

Here's some setup information: I have a struct with iterates all found query within text content.

```rust
pub struct QueryRangeItr<'a> {
    inverted: bool,
    query: &'a str,
    content: &'a str,
}
```

It takes a reference of the query and content and expects the instance to last as long as the query/content. So far, so good.

```rust
impl<'a> QueryRangeItr<'a> {
    fn new(query: &'a str, content: &'a str, inverted: bool) -> QueryRangeItr<'a> {
        Self {
            inverted,
            query,
            content,
        }
    }
}
```

I have a static method that allows you to perform a transformation on each found query. It takes a closure and applies it to the queries, then gives you a new `String` which has no lifetime dependencies. Because the return value has no lifetime, I don't actually *want* to bring lifetimes to the query and content here, but if I don't, Rust tells me I need to... thus, they have lifetime requirements. By itself, this works fine.

The problem occurs on another static method that calls `transform` twice to transform both the query *and* non-query content. It first calls `transfrom` to apply one closure to found query. The results are fed back to another call of the `transform` method, but this time to apply a transform to the rest of the content.

```rust
impl<'a> QueryRangeItr<'a> {
    pub fn transform<T>(
        query: &'a str,
        content: &'a str,
        transform: T,
        inverted: bool,
    ) -> String where T: Fn(&str) -> String {
        let selects = Self::new(query, content, true);
        // ...
        // returns a `String` with no lifetime dependency on input params
    }

    pub fn transform_all<TQ, TNQ>(
        query: &'a str,
        content: &'a str,
        transform_query: TQ,
        transform_non_query: TNQ,
    ) -> String
        where
            TQ: Fn(&str) -> String,
            TNQ: Fn(&str) -> String,
    {
        let transformed_content = Self::transform(query, content, &transform_query, false);
        let transformed_query = transform_query(query);
        let transformed = Self::transform(&transformed_query, &transformed_content, transform_non_query, true); // <--- Rust expects `transformed_content` and `transformed_query` to match the lifetime of `query` and `content`
        transformed
    }

}
```

`transformed_content` and `transformed_query` both die at the end of `transform_all`... which makes sense, but Rust wants them to last as long as the input params `query` and `content` ('a)... and the won't.

I don't *actually* need them to live any longer. Once I get `transformed` back, I have no further need for them. However, having lifetimes on `query` and `content` make Rust think they need to last longer than they really need to and I get this error:

```
115 | impl<'a> QueryRangeItr<'a> {
    |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
200 |         let transformed = Self::transform(&transformed_query, &transformed_content, transform_non_query, true);
    |                           ------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^----------------------------
    |                           |                                   |
    |                           |                                   borrowed value does not live long enough
    |                           argument requires that `transformed_content` is borrowed for `'a`
201 |         transformed
202 |     }
    |     - `transformed_content` dropped here while still borrowed
```

and if I remove lifetimes I get this error:

```
error[E0621]: explicit lifetime required in the type of `query`
   --> src/range/query_range_iterator.rs:130:23
    |
125 |         query: &str,
    |                ---- help: add explicit lifetime `'a` to the type of `query`: `&'a str`
...
130 |         let selects = Self::new(query, content, invert);
    |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lifetime `'a` required
```

And, if I try to define a different lifetime that `'a` (`'b` or `'_`) for my transform methods, I get something like this:

```
error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of associated function
   --> src/range/query_range_iterator.rs:130:23
    |
126 |         content: &'_ str,
    |         ------- `content` is a reference that is only valid in the associated function body
...
130 |         let selects = Self::new(query, content, invert);
    |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `content` escapes the associated function body here
```

What I want to do is find a way to prove to Rust that I don't need `transformed_content` and `transformed_query` as long as it thinks.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I asked a concise Question for a similar common rust error `error[E0716]` [error E0716: temporary value dropped while borrowed (rust)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71626083/error-e0716-temporary-value-dropped-while-borrowed-rust). It links back to this Question.

Answer (score 7):

Replace

```rust
 = Self::transform(&transformed_query, &transformed_content, ...
// ^^^^
```

with

```rust
 = QueryRangeItr::transform(&transformed_query, &transformed_content, ...
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

By using `Self`, you're using the same lifetime `'a` for everything. And as you've pointed out, `transformed_content` and `transformed_query` only live within the function, so their lifetime is definitely shorter and cannot match `'a`. Replacing `Self` with `QueryRangeItr` allows the compiler to pick a new lifetime `'a` for the call.